# How do I get the HP Heart in the Yoshi Sphinx?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

I've completed the Yoshi Sphinx level multiple times, and I've even used the Door sticker to open the treasure room.  But I still haven't found a path leading to the +5HP heart.  How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are on top of the Sphinx, near where the Sticker Comet is, walk north/to the top of the screen, and slide off the top of the Sphinx. If you do it correctly, you should be able to reach the HP-Up Heart with ease.

[image]
[image]

Images sourced from the [IGN guide](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/paper-mario-sticker-star/World_2-2_Yoshi_Sphinx).

Comment: It's important to note that you should slide off Yoshi's back from the middle of the screen (near the Sticker Comet) rather than near the door as shown in the first image.